# Detecting if a character in a String is an emoticon (using Android)

Tags: java, android, emoticons

Like the title says. I want to find out if a given java String contains an emoticon.

I can't use `Character.UnicodeBlock.of(char) == Character.UnicodeBlock.EMOTICONS` since that requires API level 19.

[I found this code for iOS](https://gist.github.com/cihancimen/4146056) but it isn't really applicable since it looks like java and objective-c handle surrogate pairs in different manners.

The documentations I've looked through tell me that:

```
A char value, therefore, represents Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) code points, including the surrogate code points, or code units of the UTF-16 encoding
```

I'm not quite sure what that means. Does that simply mean that they also include the BMP point as their first number?

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) the emoticon set lies between 0x1f600 and 0x1f64f but I don't know how to check if the char is in that range.

I had hoped that something like this would work but it didn't

```
if (0x1f600 <= a && a <= 0x1f64f)
{
    Print.d("Unicode", "groovy!");
}
```

So how do I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in fact able to use the linked iOS code to create the following function. I didn't realize that a String that contains, for example, a single emoticon will have a length of 2. So you can check if a character is in fact a surrogate.

I'm not entirely sure how to handle `else if (substring.length > 1)` from the iOS code but I think `Character.isHighSurrogate(myChar)` does the same job in that instance.

```
private boolean containsIllegalCharacters(String displayName)
{
    final int nameLength = displayName.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < nameLength; i++)
    {
        final char hs = displayName.charAt(i);

        if (0xd800 <= hs && hs <= 0xdbff)
        {
            final char ls = displayName.charAt(i + 1);
            final int uc = ((hs - 0xd800) * 0x400) + (ls - 0xdc00) + 0x10000;

            if (0x1d000 <= uc && uc <= 0x1f77f)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (Character.isHighSurrogate(hs))
        {
            final char ls = displayName.charAt(i + 1);

            if (ls == 0x20e3)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // non surrogate
            if (0x2100 <= hs && hs <= 0x27ff)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (0x2B05 <= hs && hs <= 0x2b07)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (0x2934 <= hs && hs <= 0x2935)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (0x3297 <= hs && hs <= 0x3299)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (hs == 0xa9 || hs == 0xae || hs == 0x303d || hs == 0x3030 || hs == 0x2b55 || hs == 0x2b1c || hs == 0x2b1b || hs == 0x2b50)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

*Four years later...*

At this time, it might make more sense to take advantage of `EmojiCompat`. This code presumes you initialized `EmojiCompat` when your app was starting up. The basic idea here is to have `EmojiCompat` process your `CharSequence`, inserting instances of `EmojiSpan` wherever any emoji appear, and then examine the results.

```
public static boolean containsEmoji(CharSequence charSequence) {
    boolean result = false;
    CharSequence processed = EmojiCompat.get().process(charSequence, 0, charSequence.length() -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, EmojiCompat.REPLACE_STRATEGY_ALL);
    if (processed instanceof Spannable) {
        Spannable spannable = (Spannable) processed;
        result = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length() - 1, EmojiSpan.class).length > 0;
    }
    return  result;
}
```

If you want to collect a list of the unique emoji that appear within a given `CharSequence`, you could do something like this, iterating over the results of `getSpans()` and finding the start and end of each span to capture the emoji discovered by `EmojiCompat`:

```
@NonNull
public static List<String> getUniqueEmoji(CharSequence charSequence) {
    Set<String> emojiList = new HashSet<>();
    CharSequence processed = EmojiCompat.get().process(charSequence, 0, charSequence.length() -1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, EmojiCompat.REPLACE_STRATEGY_ALL);
    if (processed instanceof Spannable) {
        Spannable spannable = (Spannable) processed;

        EmojiSpan[] emojiSpans = spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length() - 1, EmojiSpan.class);
        for (EmojiSpan emojiSpan : emojiSpans) {
            int spanStart = spannable.getSpanStart(emojiSpan);
            int spanEnd = spannable.getSpanEnd(emojiSpan);
            CharSequence emojiCharSequence = spannable.subSequence(spanStart, spanEnd);
            emojiList.add(String.valueOf(emojiCharSequence));
        }
    }
    return emojiList.size() > 0 ? new ArrayList<>(emojiList) : new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

UPDATE: Here's an example of EmojiCompat initialization. This static method can be called from your Application onCreate() method, passing in the Application itself as the Context param.

```
@JvmStatic
fun initEmojiCompat(context: Context) {
    if (emojiCompatConfig != null) {
        // alternatively, EmojiCompat.reset() could be called here
        logger().w(LOGTAG, "EmojiCompat already initialized.")
        return
    }

    // "Noto Color Emoji Compat" doesn't have graphics for the following emojis:
    // U+1F5E3 "speaking head" (required)
    // U+1F441 "eye" (required)
    // U+1F575 "detective" (nice to have)
    val fontRequest = FontRequest(
        "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
        "com.google.android.gms",
        "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
        R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
    )

    emojiCompatConfig = FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(context, fontRequest)
        .setReplaceAll(false)
        .setEmojiSpanIndicatorEnabled(false)
        .registerInitCallback(initCallback)
        .also {
            EmojiCompat.init(it)
        }
}
```

Comment: I realize it's been years, but it would be a wonder if you added information on how to initialize `EmojiCompat`

Comment: @slezica - No problem! I just added an example.

Answer (score 5):

This is how Telegram does it:

```
private static boolean isEmoji(String message){
    return message.matches("(?:[\uD83C\uDF00-\uD83D\uDDFF]|[\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF]|" +
        "[\uD83D\uDE00-\uD83D\uDE4F]|[\uD83D\uDE80-\uD83D\uDEFF]|" +
        "[\u2600-\u26FF]\uFE0F?|[\u2700-\u27BF]\uFE0F?|\u24C2\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\uD83C\uDDE6-\uD83C\uDDFF]{1,2}|" +
        "[\uD83C\uDD70\uD83C\uDD71\uD83C\uDD7E\uD83C\uDD7F\uD83C\uDD8E\uD83C\uDD91-\uD83C\uDD9A]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3|[\u2194-\u2199\u21A9-\u21AA]\uFE0F?|[\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u2934\u2935]\uFE0F?|[\u3030\u303D]\uFE0F?|[\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\uD83C\uDE01\uD83C\uDE02\uD83C\uDE1A\uD83C\uDE2F\uD83C\uDE32-\uD83C\uDE3A\uD83C\uDE50\uD83C\uDE51]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u203C\u2049]\uFE0F?|[\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u00A9\u00AE]\uFE0F?|[\u2122\u2139]\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDC04\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDCCF\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA]\uFE0F?)+");
}
```

It is [Line 21,026](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DrKLO/Telegram/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/ChatActivity.java).

Comment: Telegram dev is hella insane, line "21.036"?? Code guidelines are just a suggestion I guess

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Kotlin that relies on java.lang.Character api (granted the original poster can't use this). I have found it pretty reliably tells apart an emoji from 'special characters' and non-latin alphabets etc. Try it.

```
import java.lang.Character.*
import java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.MISCELLANEOUS_TECHNICAL
import java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.MISCELLANEOUS_SYMBOLS
import java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.VARIATION_SELECTORS

fun isStringEmoji(someString: String): Boolean {
    if (someString.isNotEmpty() && someString.length < 5) {
        val firstCodePoint = codePointAt(someString, 0)
        val lastCodePoint = codePointBefore(someString, someString.length)
        if (isValidCodePoint(firstCodePoint) && isValidCodePoint(lastCodePoint)) {
            if (isSupplementaryCodePoint(firstCodePoint) ||
                isSupplementaryCodePoint(lastCodePoint) ||
                UnicodeBlock.of(firstCodePoint) == MISCELLANEOUS_SYMBOLS ||
                UnicodeBlock.of(firstCodePoint) == MISCELLANEOUS_TECHNICAL ||
                UnicodeBlock.of(lastCodePoint) == VARIATION_SELECTORS
            ) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if (Integer.parseInt("1f600", 16) <= (int)'☺' && (int)'☺' <= Integer.parseInt("1f64f", 16)) {
    Print.d("Unicode", "groovy!");
}
```

This might work because the hexidecimal value and the char value are both being converted to ints.

Comment: Sorry to say that this didn't work but thanks anyway.