# How to check whether a char is smiley or not in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoji

I have an editText, while a user types text how I can check the entered string is whether smiley or not?

please help

Answer (score 1):

you can restrict use for entering other values than you set for editext

```
android:digits="123abcd"
```

where "`123abcd`" is values will be accepted by editext

Comment: Thanks for responding Hitesh, Actually here I want smileys in my editText, I have to send them to a server in another format, So I want to identify smileys and replace them with some text

Comment: why you need to send in another format? because smiley will be taken as text when you get it from edittext

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392969/detecting-if-a-character-in-a-string-is-an-emoticon-using-android refer this link for info

Answer (score 1):

Add `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and check whether user entered you smiley character or not in `onTextChenged()` on every entry.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Check your criteria for smiley face using CharSequence s
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```